# Solve number of substrings having two unique characters in O(n)

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on a series of substring problem:

Given a string:

1. Find the substring containing only two unique characters that has maximum length.
2. Find the number of all substrings containing AT MOST two unique characters.
3. Find the number of all substrings containing two unique characters.

Seems like problem 1 and 2 has O(n) solution. However I cannot think of a O(n) solution for problem 3.([Here](http://coders-stop.blogspot.in/2012/09/directi-online-test-number-of.html) is the solution for problem 2 and [here](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=17221689) is for problem 1.).

So I would like to know does a O(n) solution for problem 3 exist or not?

Adding sample input/output for problem 3:

`Given: abbac`

`Return: 6`

Because there are 6 substring containing two unique chars:
ab,abb,abba,bba,ba,ac

Comment: Sure. Given a string that has at most two unique characters, can you find out how many non-empty substrings it has? Out of those, how many have just one unique character? The rest must have exactly two.

Comment: @n.m. I just need a number, not a set containing all substrings satisfying the condition. That is a O(2^n) problem. I think your way is based on I'm already having all substrings that contains at most two unique characters.

Comment: Could you write an example input and output?

Comment: Yes you should already have a way to identify all maximal (i.e. not extendable) substrings of no more than 2 unique characters. You need them for the first two problems anyway. That's an O(n) job. Then you need to identify all maximal substrings of 1 unique character, also O(n). Then you just need to calculate how many smaller substrings there are. You don't have to identify or build them all.

Comment: @Jun -- looks like you might not need this any more, but I corrected my answer.

Comment: For a string `abab`, should the substring `ab` be counted twice?

Comment: @DaveGalvin Thanks. I'll of course take a look. The more solutions the better:)

Comment: @anatolyg Yes. You can denote any substring as a vector [i,j], where i is start index and j is end index. So it does not really matter if they are the same strings.

Answer (score 1):

> Find the number of all substrings containing two unique characters.

**Edit** : I misread the question. This solution finds unique substrings with *at least* 2 unique characters

1. The number of substrings for a given word whose length is `len` is given by `len * (len + 1) / 2`

   sum = `len * (len + 1) / 2`

   1. We are looking for substrings whose length is greater than 1. The above formula includes  substrings which are of length 1. We need to substract those substrings.

So the total number of 2 letter substrings now is `len * (len + 1) / 2 - l`.

```
sum = `len * (len + 1) / 2 - l`
```

1. Find the longest consecutive run of characters which are alike. Apply step `1` and `2`.
   Subtract this current sum from the `sum` as obtained from step 2.

Sample implementation follows.

```
public static int allUniq2Substrings(char s[]) {
    int sum = s.length * (s.length + 1) / 2 - s.length;
    int sameRun = 0;
    for (int i = 0, prev = -1; i < s.length; prev = s[i++]) {
        if (s[i] != prev) {
            sum -= sameRun * (sameRun + 1) / 2 - sameRun;
            sameRun = 1;
        } else {
            sameRun++;
        }
    }

    return sum - (sameRun * (sameRun + 1) / 2 - sameRun);

}
```

---

```
allUniq2Substrings("aaac".toCharArray());
3

allUniq2Substrings("aabc".toCharArray());
5

allUniq2Substrings("aaa".toCharArray());
0

allUniq2Substrings("abcd".toCharArray());
6
```

**Edit**
Let me try this again. I use the above **3** invariants.
This is a subproblem of finding all substrings which contain at least 2 unique characters.
I have a method posted above which gives me unique substrings for any length. I will use it to generate substrings from a set which contains at 2 unique characters.

We only need to keep track of the longest consequent run of characters whose set length is 2. ie Any permutation of 2 unique characters. The sum of such runs gives us the total number of desired substrings.

```
public static int allUniq2Substrings(char s[]) {
    int sum = s.length * (s.length + 1) / 2 - s.length;
    int sameRun = 0;
    for (int i = 0, prev = -1; i < s.length; prev = s[i++]) {
        if (s[i] != prev) {
            sum -= sameRun * (sameRun + 1) / 2 - sameRun;
            sameRun = 1;
        } else {
            sameRun++;
        }
    }

    return sum - (sameRun * (sameRun + 1) / 2 - sameRun);

}

public static int uniq2substring(char s[]) {
    int last = 0, secondLast = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[i - 1]) {
            last = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    boolean OneTwo = false;
    int oneTwoIdx = -1; //alternating pattern

    for (int i = last + 1; i < s.length; ++i) {
        if (s[secondLast] != s[i] && s[last] != s[i]) { //detected more than 2 uniq chars
            sum += allUniq2Substrings(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, secondLast, i));
            secondLast = last;
            last = i;
            if (OneTwo) {
                secondLast = oneTwoIdx;
            }
            OneTwo = false;
        } else if (s[i] != last) { //alternating pattern detected a*b*a
            OneTwo = true;
            oneTwoIdx = i;
        }

    }

    return sum + allUniq2Substrings(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, secondLast, s.length));
}
```

---

```
uniq2substring("abaac".toCharArray())
6


uniq2substring("aab".toCharArray())
2

uniq2substring("aabb".toCharArray())
4

uniq2substring("ab".toCharArray())
1
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but those results don't look right to me. I would expect `"aabc" -> {"aab", "ab", "bc"}` (3, not 5), and `"abcd" -> {"ab", "bc", "cd"}` (3, not 6).

Comment: Sorry I thought the question was to find unique substrings with at least 2 unique characters. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the link posted by you for the solution of the problem 2

http://coders-stop.blogspot.in/2012/09/directi-online-test-number-of.html

can we very easily be modelled for the solution of the third problem as well.
Just modify the driver program as under

```
int numberOfSubstrings ( string A ) {
    int len = A.length();
    int res = 0, j = 1, c = 1, a[2][2];
    a[0][0] = A[0]; a[0][1] = 1; 
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        >>int start = -1;
        for (;j<len; j++) {

           c = isInArray(a, c, A[j]);
           >> if (c == 2 && start != - 1) start = j;
           if(c == -1) break;  
        }
        >>c = removeFromArray(a,A[i]);
        res = (res + j - start);
    }
    return res;
}
```

The complete explanation on the derivation can be found in the link itself :)